# Open Xterm partially off screen

Tags: window, xterm

I would like to open an xterm (or any X window) so that it is partially off screen. The X man page says you can do this:

*-geometry WIDTHxHEIGHT+XOFF+YOFF
+YOFF
The top edge of the window is to be YOFF pixels below the top edge of the screen (i.e., the Y coordinate of the window's origin will be YOFF). YOFF may be negative, in which case the window's top edge will be off the screen.*

This doesn't seem to work and I have tried this on SuSE and Fedora. The X man page also says:

*Although many window managers will honor geometry specifications as given, others may choose to ignore them (requiring the user to explicitly draw the window's region on the screen with the pointer, for example).*

Does anyone know if there is a config setting or some way to get this to work?